# Where is the source for official docker images?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The dockerfile examples I've seen like below

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
```

start from a base official docker image, but how are these official docker images built? I searched the [official image page for openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk) and could not find where the source is for its dockerfile.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/8/jre/buster/Dockerfile

Comment: You're looking for the "Supported tags and respective `Dockerfile` links" section on that page.

Comment: @medilies how did you get that link from docker hub ?

Comment: @DavidMaze where in that section is the link that medilies has? Or another example ,https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox , to the GitHub source ?

Comment: The `busybox` image page is easier to follow: all of the tags under that exact section header are links to Dockerfiles.  On the `openjdk` page that section header has a link to the GitHub repository (@medilies 's first link) which has the full contents, including a very long list of links to Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can search them using https://hub.docker.com/ there is almost always README on images that are commonly used and you'll find there a github (reference or any other versionning tool) in most cases.